# How do I control the DisplayForModel method in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

If I use [DisplayForModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayformodel(v=VS.100).aspx) in a strongly-typed ASP.NET MVC 2 View with an EntityObject model, then unwanted field labels are displayed:

- EntityState
- EntityKey

How can I control the output to hide these?

Answer (score 3):

Personally I would create a view specific presentation model with only the fields I wanted to display.

If you haven't already seen the [blog post series](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) from Brad Wilson on display templates, I would recommend reading over them.

In part 2 he mentions the `ShowForDisplay` piece of metadata, but I couldn't find where to set or manipulate it.

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: [ScaffoldColumn] (from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations)
This will set both the ShowForDisplay and ShowForEdit properties.